# Asp.net request.From and Hidden field not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me. I am new to ASP.NET . I am testing request.From. In my asp.net page I have code like this.  When I click the button .I dont see any text in the label .Please help me .Why ? explain me

```
<input name="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="This is hidden field" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Request.Form["Hidden"];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Label1.Text = Request.Form["Hidden1"];`?

Comment: try to use Label1.Text = Request.Form["Hidden1"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written wrong code:- Please change like this

```
Label1.Text = Request.Form["Hidden1"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much .I am not a smart person .That is what i found out myself

Comment: @user3248713: Its ok, we make mistakes.